# OpenTripPlanner: Get GTFS and OSM data

Tags: openstreetmap, gtfs, opentripplanner

I've managed to install OTP on my computer using Git Bash. I was trying to follow the OTP Basic Usage to get some data, but I cannot do it.

Can someone explain me how to do it? Or maybe give a link with a sample that I can follow?

Thank you,

Paula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find OSM data for your region. Mapzen's metro extracts service is a good place to start:

https://mapzen.com/data/metro-extracts/

Then find your region's GTFS files. 
http://transitfeeds.com and
https://transit.land/feed-registry/ are comprehensive sources of where to find them.

Once you have downloaded those, the OTP directions should be easy to follow.